# Android push Notification sample

Tags: android, push-notification

I refered Link [Here](http://androidmaterial.blogspot.in/2011/08/android-cloud-to-device-messaging-c2dm.html#comment-form) and Implemented sample android Push Notification.I have already registered in C2DM Server but still I can't send a message to the Emulator because of error in sendMessage() Method.and also while registering i gave 2 Id (id 1 as a Contactmail id2 as a senderid).during runtime clientside(i gave id1) and serverside (stored pref also Id1) its correct are i want to change reply me.Thank u

Comment: Take a look here: http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to receive C2DM message create emulator and select target SDK of Google APIs(Google Inc.) - API level 8(use api level 8 or more). Because C2DM feature was introduced from OS Version 2.2.
**Always use Google APIs more than level 8.**
 [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) you can get end-to-end detail. Also useful from server side.